# C Update GUI element of GTK3

Tags: c, gtk

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

GtkBuilder *builder;
GtkWidget *window;
GtkImage *image;
GtkButton *but;
char s[1000];

void on_button1_button_press_event(GtkWidget *but, gpointer  data)
{
    strcpy(s, "/home/linux/testing2.png");
    gtk_widget_queue_draw (image);
}

int main(void)
{
    gtk_init(NULL, NULL);
    builder = gtk_builder_new();
    gtk_builder_add_from_file(builder, "/home/linux/gui.xml", NULL);
    window = (GtkWidget *) gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "window1");
    image = (GtkImage *) gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "image1");
    but = (GtkButton *) gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "button1");
    gtk_image_set_from_file(image, strcpy(s, "/home/linux/testing1.png"));
    g_signal_connect(but, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(on_button1_button_press_event), NULL);
    gtk_widget_show(window);
    gtk_main();

    return 0;
}
```

When I click on "button1", "callback" function called, and it updates string s then I want gtk refresh "image1" with gtk_widget_queue_draw. But "image1" have not changed.

Comment: Please post the code, there is no way to help without code. Specifically show what exactly is called after the file path changes, and what did you attempt that did not work. In principle, you can call [gtk_widget_queue_draw()](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWidget.html#gtk-widget-queue-draw) for this, but in practice if you set a new image this function should be called automatically.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have posted my sample code.

Answer (score 0):

`gtk_widget_queue_draw()` takes a string with the filename of the image. But it does not keep the string you pass. Instead the widget stores the whole loaded image.

So your `s` variable is useless, and changing it does nothing. You should do instead, in `main()`:

```
gtk_image_set_from_file(image, "/home/linux/testing1.png");
```

and in the event callback:

```
gtk_image_set_from_file(image, "/home/linux/testing2.png");
```

There is no need to call `gtk_widget_queue_draw()` because changing the image does that automatically.

Comment: Thank you for your explain. But is it possible to use my s variable?

Comment: @cuncon- Sure you can, it is your variable, but what for? The widget do not keep a pointer to the string, and you are only using literal strings... so why do you want to use it?

Comment: It seems I did a redundant thing. Ah, I want to ask 2 more questions.
1. I want to show/hide a entire window when an event occurs. I use gtk_widget_show/hide(). Is it right way?
2. Is it possible to monitor file in gtk_main loop?

Comment: @cuncon- Ah, those are different questions! 1: Yes, I think that is correct. 2: It is possible but the details vary depending on what you mean with _monitor a file_. You should really ask a new question with the details of exactly you want to do (comments are not for new questions).